# How to write write/edit text under body of content document with having no ID for text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have very minimal knowledge of *JavaScript* so pardon me if it is very basic question.

I am unable to edit text under body of a "*content document*" within a website "*document*".

I read that by using text id we can access that particular text in document but in this document I don't have any id for text and hence I can not access that text.

I tried to use **contentDocument.body.innertext** but it is not saving on reloading the page.

[see in this picture i want to edit the red underlined text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoXu5.png)

please help anyone ?

Comment: you can just add an ```id``` or ```class``` tag to the div containing the text, then reference it using javascript

Comment: **I tried to use contentDocument.body.innertext but it is not saving on reloading the page.**. This makes me think you are trying all those in the browser console

Comment: yes i am trying on browser console , does it create problem?

Comment: Use sessionStorage, localStorage, or a backend if you want changes to persist between reloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the document body text with:

```
var body_text = document.body.text;
document.write(body_text);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a7hkmepx/

**UPDATED:**
If you want to save this information to the server you can attach jquery framework to your html document then use an ajax call back to the server. On the server you can decide if you want to write the text to a file or to a mysql database

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){

var body_text = document.body.text;
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { text: body_text },
  dataType: "html"
});

});
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php

if ($_POST)
{

$text_returned = $_POST["text"];

// save text_returned variable here with whatever method you choose

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer ! 
Document.write() also does not save the text after reloading the page ! I want to save the edited text

Comment: @PAVANKUMAR I updated my answer.  If this helps please check it as answered.